# Better solving method other than if -else

Tags: android

Thanks in advance for any reply. I currently working on android application that let user select several option from 10 spinner type(dropdownlist). But for every onChanged click in spinner, i have to check other spinner item for making a query in cursor. I thinking to use if-else statement to solve it as if-else statement was the easier way to approach the outcome i need but it will consume too many LOC and is not very efficient when modification of code is needed.

Sorry to demand solution from you guy but i cant figure a better method.

Comment: Either try using events or if you just want to make the code a little neater use switch instead of bunch of if-else

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to store the last known value of the dropdown into a variable, and then run through those stored variables on click.

```
var storedVaribles[10];

OnChanged(int i, var changedVariable)
{
   storedVariables[i] = changedVariable;
   checkWithAllStoredVariables(storedVariables);
}
```

This is only pseudocode, but it should give you an idea of the direction to head with the solution.

erhaps this type of question would be more appropriate on CodeReview.

Answer (score 0):

You have control of your spinner Adapters. Try to construct your data such that you directly obtain the information that belongs in your query. The basic idea is to have an object like this:

```
class SpinnerItem {
    String displayTitle;
    String querySyntax;

    public SpinnerItem(String title, string sql) {
        displayTitle = title;
        querySyntax = sql;
    }
}
```

Then make a `SpinnerAdapter` that keeps an array or a list of these objects. In `getView()`, you would bind the `displayTitle` to a TextView that the user sees. When you want to compose your query, you can call

```
SpinnerItem item = adapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
// use item.querySyntax in your query
```

As a very simple example, suppose I have a table with contacts, and each contact has either an email or phone number. I want the query to filter on this type based on the selected spinner item. Here's how I might build it:

```
List<SpinnerItem> items = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();
items.add(new SpinnerItem("All", "1"));
items.add(new SpinnerItem("Phone numbers only", "type = 'phone'"));
items.add(new SpinnerItem("Emails only", "type = 'email'"));
MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

// later when building query ...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("select * from table where ");
SpinnerItem item = adapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
builder.append(item.querySyntax);
String sql = builder.toString();
```

Comment: I currently using code below as query to run my application then show it on a list view. Do it compatible ? Since if more spinner item are chose, more argument of query have to put in the query.
`d = myReadDatabase.query("Card", fromColumns, "Instant = ?", new String[] { "True" }, null, null, null);`

Comment: I don't have the ability to know if this approach suits your needs. The important point is the idea that you can do some additional setup to avoid complicated and brittle logic later. You can take this idea and modify it to suit your situation better if it doesn't quite fit the way I described it.

Comment: i modified the code but i'm stuck on the string[] argument part as it have to create new string[] for each diff argument and it not allow to change old string[] that i created before.